# Problems with the pseudo selector not applied in a styled-component

Tags: reactjs

To create a round-shaped check box, I try to apply the style using the label tag. When props are delivered to the component and the value is true, the style for ":after" is not applied.

I've tried putting two colons in front of "after" and tried many other experiments, but none of the methods worked.

I should not write a css file and apply className to each component. This is my company's rule for efficient code maintenance.

I look forward to your wise answer.

This is a whole code.

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function App() {
    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

    const onClickCheck = () => {
        setIsChecked(!isChecked);
        console.log(!isChecked);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <SCustomCheckboxWrapper>
                <SCustomCheckbox type="checkbox" isChecked={isChecked} />
                <SCustomLabel onClick={onClickCheck} isChecked={isChecked} />
            </SCustomCheckboxWrapper>
        </>
    );
}

const SCustomCheckboxWrapper = styled.div`
    position: relative;
`;

const SCustomCheckbox = styled.input`
    visibility: hidden;
    ${({ isChecked }) =>
        isChecked
            ? {
                  backgroundColor: "#66bb6a",
                  borderColor: "#66bb6a",
                  "&:after": {
                      opacity: 1
                  }
              }
            : null}
`;

const SCustomLabel = styled.label`
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    ${({ isChecked }) =>
        isChecked
            ? {
                  backgroundColor: "#66bb6a",
                  borderColor: "#66bb6a",
                  "&:after": {
                      border: "2px solid #fff",
                      borderTop: "none",
                      borderRight: "none",
                      content: "",
                      height: 6,
                      left: "7px",
                      opacity: 0,
                      position: "absolute",
                      top: "8px",
                      transform: "rotate(-45deg)",
                      width: 12
                  }
              }
            : {
                  backgroundColor: "#fff",
                  "&:after": { opacity: 1 }
              }}
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be because of the content.
Try this:

```
const SCustomCheckbox = styled.input`
  visibility: hidden;
  ${({ isChecked }) =>
    isChecked
      ? {
          backgroundColor: "#66bb6a",
          borderColor: "#66bb6a",
          "&:after": {
            content: {
              opacity: 1
            }
          }
        }
      : null};
`;
```

Comment: Although content was added by referring to the your answer, the same problem still persists.

Comment: I was able to solve this problem by using another option in the styled-components module called css. Thank you very much! Have a nice day~!!

Comment: 2 things, first: use the correct pseudo call, that is 2 colons before "after" ``::after``, second: consider the template string, so call the pseudo value on the string, and use the props again.